# Using global optimization Matlab toolbox and genetic algorithm to minimize black-box function

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

I have following objective function:

```
function w = objective_function(a,b,c,d)
    function w = rh(t,y) 
        w = [y(2);6*cos(9*t) - 10*sin(3*t) - a*y(1) - b*(1-y(1)^2)*y(2)];
    end
    t = linspace(0,20,20000);
    [t,y] = ode45(@rh,t,[c;d]);
    u = 2*sin(3*t);
    w = norm(y(:,1)-u,Inf)/norm(u,Inf);
end
```

and I would like to find its minimum using genetic algorithm and globaloptimization toolbox, so I wrote following script:

```
    a = optimvar("a","LowerBound",0,"UpperBound",10);
    b = optimvar("b","LowerBound",0,"UpperBound",10);
    c = optimvar("c","LowerBound",-5,"UpperBound",5);
    d = optimvar("d","LowerBound",-5,"UpperBound",5);
    prob = optimproblem("Objective",objective_function(a,b,c,d));
    options = optimoptions("ga","PlotFcn","gaplotbestf");
    rng default
    [sol,fval] = solve(prob,"Solver","ga","Options",options)
```

and I got following error when I run it:

```
    Error using superiorfloat
    Inputs must be floats, namely single or double.

    Error in odearguments (line 114)
        dataType = superiorfloat(t0,y0,f0);

    Error in ode45 (line 104)
        odearguments(odeIsFuncHandle,odeTreatAsMFile, solver_name, ode, 
        tspan, y0, options, varargin);

    Error in objective_function (line 13)
        [t,y] = ode45(rh,[0,10],[c;d]);

    Error in script (line 6)
        prob = optimproblem("Objective",objective_function(a,b,c,d));
```

How to fix this problem?

I don't understand why genetic algorithm fails (it only require evaluation of the values of the objective_function for each set of parameters (a,b,c,d) and this requirement is fullfilled). I don't understand error which I got (code and erros are presented above).

Comment: it's not an error related to the genetic algorithm, it is ode45 related. See if here you can find a soltion: https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/399165-inputs-must-be-floats-namely-single-or-double-ode45-function

Comment: @FerroLuca I'm not sure about it. When I run function objective_function separatly `objective_function(4,-1,0,6)` there is no errors and I get answer `0.1408`.

Comment: I've added line `syms t; syms y;` to objective_function as is adviced in link and errors messages were the same as before.

Comment: the thing he does not like is that you are giving him variables (a,b,c,d) of type `optim.problemdef.OptimizationVariable` instead of floats, doubles etc in the call `prob = optimproblem("Objective",objective_function(a,b,c,d));`

Comment: to pass the objective function you need to create a `optim.problemdef.OptimizationExpression` instead of passing straight up the function i think

Comment: @FerroLuca I replaced `optimproblem("Objective",objective_function(a,b,c,d));` with two lines `prob = optimproblem;` and `optim.problemdef.OptimizationExpression = objective_function(a,b,c,d);` . The error messages were the same :(